# Problems at Laravel seed

Tags: laravel

Im Laravel beginner and im trying to seed a simple DB. The question is about a problem with foreign key's. I read the documentation but I didn't find any solution.

This is the error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vlogit`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`user_id`, `category_id`, `name`, `slug`, `excerpt`, `body`, `file`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (28, 18, Voluptas qui ut., voluptas-qui-ut, Sint qui ut a rem doloribus. Minima perferendis dolorem totam accusantium incidunt eveniet ipsa. Quisquam qui non sed tempore molestiae cum. Assumenda vitae voluptas optio aut dolor velit., Corrupti optio esse omnis laboriosam commodi consequatur ut blanditiis. Labore et iste atque accusamus magnam magnam id. Consequuntur odit sequi saepe earum ipsam. Aut nihil sapiente repellendus recusandae. Maxime quia enim qui. Mollitia illum accusamus sit non itaque perspiciatis. Est ullam ullam placeat consequatur fugiat ut. Velit laudantium et praesentium. Necessitatibus nobis illo modi ut consectetur fuga dolorem labore. Sed sed in quisquam voluptatem. Ea sit ad officiis quam quam., https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400.png/0066cc?text=voluptas, PUBLISHED, 2020-11-21 23:46:59, 2020-11-21 23:46:59))

The DB is about a simple blog, with User, Category, Post and Tag columns. The DB is correctly working with posts, categories and users, but not with post_tags. I think that error is produced here:

The migration:post_tag_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            
            //Relaciones
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');
    }
}
```

PostFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        
        $title = $this->faker->sentence(4);
        return [
            
            'user_id'       => rand(1,30),
            'category_id'   => rand(1,20),
            'name'          => $title,
            'slug'          => Str::slug($title),
            'excerpt' => $this->faker->text(200),
            'body' => $this->faker->text(500),
            'file' => $this->faker->imageUrl($width = 1200, $height = 400),
            'status' =>$this->faker->randomElement(['DRAFT', 'PUBLISHED']),
        ];
    }
}
```

TagFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Tag;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class TagFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Tag::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $title = $this->faker->sentence(4);
        return [
            
        'name' => $title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
            
        ];
    }
}
```

PostTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        
        //      
        \App\Models\Post::factory(300)->create()->each(function(\App\Models\Post $post) {
            $post->tags()->attach([
                rand(1,5), 
                rand(6,14), 
                rand(15,20)
            ]);
            
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: All the fields that are foreign references have to have matching keys on the table they reference ... do you have 30 users in the 'users' table?

Comment: I have corrected this error. Now the laravel error not appears and I have 30 users, 30 posts, and 30 tags, on the DB but still 0  for post_tag column.

Comment: _The DB is correctly working with posts, categories and users, but not with post_tags._ but the error is for `posts` table. => _"insert into **posts** (user_id, category_id, name, slug, excerpt, body, file, status, updated_at, created_at) "_ Not for `post_tags`.

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox has pointed out there should be 30 records in users table with ids from 1-30.

However more appropriate way to define the Post factory - Laravel way is to leverage relationships via factories `'user_id' => \App\Models\User::factory()`

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        
        $title = $this->faker->sentence(4);
        return [
            
            'user_id'       => \App\Models\User::factory(),
            'category_id'   => rand(1,20),
            'name'          => $title,
            'slug'          => Str::slug($title),
            'excerpt' => $this->faker->text(200),
            'body' => $this->faker->text(500),
            'file' => $this->faker->imageUrl($width = 1200, $height = 400),
            'status' =>$this->faker->randomElement(['DRAFT', 'PUBLISHED']),
        ];
    }
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is the order of migrations

Comment: Yes, I fixed it to do 30 registers. And about 'user_id' I tried your suggestion, but still is 0 on post_tag DB column.

Comment: No yet, post_tag column is still 0. I don't know the reason why it doesn't register any data

Comment: `post_tag` column or table?

Comment: Now Laravel don't print any error, thanks to @lagbox suggestion. But is still 0 register on post_tag table.

Comment: The order of seeding is the correct, User, Category, Post and Tag, but I don't know the reason why post_tag table doesn't save any data.

Comment: Solved. It was a problem at DatabaseSeeder.php.

Comment: $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(TagsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);

Comment: @José Great. Good to know that your issue is resolved. If this answer helped you may upvote/accept for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a problem on the general seeder file.

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(TagsTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);
```

And now is correctly working.

CategoriesTableSeeder.php

```
 public function definition()
    {
        
        $title = $this->faker->sentence(4);
        return [
            
        'name' => $title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($title),
        'body' => $this->faker->text(500),
            
  
        ];
    }
```

PostTableSeeder.php

```
public function definition()
{
    
    $title = $this->faker->sentence(4);
    return [
        
        'user_id'       => rand(1,30),
        'category_id'   => rand(1,30),
        'name'          => $title,
        'slug'          => Str::slug($title),
        'excerpt' => $this->faker->text(200),
        'body' => $this->faker->text(500),
        'file' => $this->faker->imageUrl($width = 1200, $height = 400),
        'status' =>$this->faker->randomElement(['DRAFT', 'PUBLISHED']),
    ];
}
```

TagTableSeeder.php

```
public function definition()
{
    $title = $this->faker->unique()->word(4);
    return [
        
    'name' => $title,
    'slug' => Str::slug($title),
        
    ];
}
```

I share the code to help other beginners.